# Framer motion parallax effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, framer-motion

I'm trying to achieve a parallax effect similar to this one using `framer-motion` in my Next.js app:

https://www.nicyiallouris.com

This is my current `ProjectCard` component:

```
"use client";

import { asText } from "@prismicio/helpers";
import { motion, useScroll, useTransform } from "framer-motion";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import type { ProjectDocumentData } from "../../../.slicemachine/prismicio";

export const ProjectCard = ({
  href,
  project,
  index,
}: {
  href: string;
  project: ProjectDocumentData;
  index: number;
}) => {
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll();
  const y = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], ["0%", `-${index * 10}%`]);

  if (!project.cover.url) return null;
  return (
    <motion.div className="sticky top-0 flex min-h-[70vh] items-center justify-center overflow-hidden">
      <Link
        href={href}
        aria-label={asText(project.title)}
        className="absolute z-10"
      >
        <h3 className="relative border-b border-brand font-brand text-lg uppercase">
          {asText(project.title)}
        </h3>
      </Link>

      <Image
        src={project.cover.url}
        width={project.cover.widescreen.dimensions?.width}
        height={project.cover.widescreen.dimensions?.height}
        alt="Project Image"
        className="absolute inset-0 h-full w-full object-cover"
        placeholder="blur"
        blurDataURL={`${project.cover.url}&blur=200`}
      />
    </motion.div>
  );
};
```

This isn't working though, the scroll effect is different, and the translate effect is pulling the project cards up above the footer. How can I get this done? Code is available here:

https://github.com/thejessewinton/ryan-spacone-www